# How to display filled information of appended row in another page?

Tags: php

This page got a button `ADD` to append the row.Once the appended row is filled,when submit,it will connect/link to another page ,then the filled information will display at that page.But the problem is how to display the filled information of appended row on 2nd page had been done in 1st page by using PHP.(Sorry for my poor English and hope for understand).

```
 <table width="600px" id="project">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_1" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_2" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_3" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <input id="addbtn" type="button" name="addbtn" value="ADD">
```

Jquery script(for append the row):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num=parseInt($("#project tr:last").text());
        num+=1;
            $("#project").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
                });
```

PHP source code(for 2nd page):

```
   <table width="600px" id="pub">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><?php echo $_post["pro_1"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><?php echo $_post["pro_2"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><?php echo $_post["pro_3"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the dynamically-added `textarea` a name, then you following page will see it as a parameter & can render it back out in the HTML.

In the Javascript:  (PLEASE don't try and munge all your code, on one line!):

```
$("#project").append("<tr>);
$("#project").append("<td>"+num);
$("#project").append("<td><textarea name='pro_"+num+"' cols='100' rows='2'></textarea>");
```

See how a pinch of readability, makes it comprehensible? I'm following the HTML spec that says `</td>` and `</tr>` are OPTIONAL, not mandatory -- I never emit them myself.

And in your PHP second page, you need to pick up the correct parameter name. (You're looking for `pub_N`, not `pro_N` which you appear to post under).

Tidy your code up, get your names right.

Then put a PHP loop around it, to render Project Names with ascending numbers until it runs out of parameters. My PHP code is rough, but..

```
<?php
$rowNum = 1;
while (true) {
    $rowValue = $_post["pro_"+$rowNum];
    if (! isset($rowValue))
        break;  // Reached the end.
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= htmlentities( $rowValue) ?></td>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh~sorry.I will make a correction of `pub` to `pro` on my post.Sorry for confuses.

Comment: should I have to use if-else statement once the `addbtn` is clicked and then put looping inside it?

Comment: AddBtn only adds one row at a time, so there's no need for a loop there.. The loop should be in your PHP page#2, to process the multiple rows received.

Comment: `<?php
       if(isset($_POST["addbtn"])){
           $num=$_POST["pro_"+num+""];
      ?>
                  <td><?php echo $num++;?></td><br/>     
                  <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_5"]; ?></td><br/>
                  <?php
       }
       ?>`

Comment: php code above never work~~what wrong with it?

Comment: 'addbtn' doesn't (and shouldn't post), it just runs Javascript. You need to check for the `pro_N` parameters being set. You can accept my answer now, BTW!

Comment: sorry ,now my mind is mess up,i just a beginner of php learner so i don't understand the parameter you mean is it `<?php echo $_POST["pro_"+num+""]; ?>` in page#2?

Comment: plz,instruct me...i need your help...