# [PHP]Why did the filled appended row didn't display and show?

Tags: php, javascript

This page got a button `ADD` to append the row.Once the appended row is filled,when submit,it will connect/link to another page ,then the filled information will display at that page.But the problem is how to display the filled information of appended row on 2nd page had been done in 1st page by using PHP.(Sorry for my poor English and hope for understand).

```
 <table width="600px" id="project">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_1" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_2" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_3" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <input id="addbtn" type="button" name="addbtn" value="ADD">
```

Jquery script(for append the row):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num=parseInt($("#project tr:last").text());
        num+=1;
            $("#project").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
                });
```

PHP source code(for 2nd page):

```
   <table width="600px" id="pub">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><?php echo $_post["pro_1"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><?php echo $_post["pro_2"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><?php echo $_post["pro_3"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="600px" id="project">
 <?php    //to show the filled appended row but fail
    $index = 1;
    while(isset($_POST["pro_".$index])) {
  ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $index; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_".$index]; ?></td>
   </tr>
  <?php 
      $index++;
   } ?>
</table>
```

the output as below:

[image]

Comment: This is the fourth time you have [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410481/how-to-display-filled-information-of-appended-row-in-another-page) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414813/why-isnt-the-appended-rows-data-displayed-after-being-submitted) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591405/why-the-appended-rows-data-didnt-displayed-after-being-submitted).

Comment: because it never work~~i had try many time but still the same thing,it make me angry~~brother....hope u understand

Comment: @crypticツ I know all of you from stackoverflow are professional one,I just beginner for the PHP and need more instruct over all of you....thank

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add `name` attribute to append command

```
name='pro_'+num;
$("#project").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea name="+name+" cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
```

Comment: the php part for `show the filled appended row` is still retain or follow your previous post?